# Defining a framework element as a resource - Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to define a framework element like a grid as an application resource?
If yes, 
 1. how do I access it?
2. where do I define the callback functions for the controls on this grid?
If this doesn't work, the backup plan that I have is to define a class extending the `Grid` class and instantiate this class wherever this grid needs to appear. Please let me know if there is a better solution.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?  If you could tell us a bit more about the "why", we might be able to help out with the "how"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is not so much a Resource but a [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). You can define a SomeGridControl.xaml and then include it in any page you want.

**SomeGridControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeApplication.SomeGridControl">
    <Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**SomePage.xaml**

```
<StackPanel xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:SomeApplication">
    <uc:SomeGridControl />
</StackPanel>
```